# ViewPager2 doesn't show correct Fragment on slow devices or when debugging

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I'm using `ViewPager2` with `TabLayout` and `FragmentStateAdapter` to display Fragments in tabs. I found out that when I run it on slower devices (ie. Nexus 5X) or when I put a breakpoint to `createFragment()` method, after I change to some later tab with Fragment, that is not created yet, Fragment on last position is shown.

In example I have 20 items. I select tab on position 15. Fragments on positions 15, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19 and 20 are created (`createFragment()` is called). I would expect to create only 14, 15, 16 to be created. On slow devices or when stopping debugger inside `createFragment()` method, Fragment on position 20 is shown.

This issue is not happening on the devices that are not slowed down.

**MainActivity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    initViewPager2WithFragments()
}

private fun initViewPager2WithFragments() {
    val viewPager2: ViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewpager)
    val adapter = ExampleStateAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
    viewPager2.adapter = adapter

    val tablayout: TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout)
    val names: Array<String> = arrayOf(
        "Fragment A",
        "Fragment B",
        "Fragment C",
        "Fragment D",
        "Fragment E",
        "Fragment F",
        "Fragment G",
        "Fragment H",
        "Fragment I",
        "Fragment J",
        "Fragment K",
        "Fragment L",
        "Fragment M",
        "Fragment N"
    )
    TabLayoutMediator(tablayout, viewPager2) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = names[position]
    }.attach()
}
}
```

**ExampleStateAdapter:**

```
class ExampleStateAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 14
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        Log.d("frg", "createFragment: $position")
        return when (position) {
            0 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("A")
            1 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("B")
            2 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("C")
            3 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("D")
            4 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("E")
            5 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("F")
            6 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("G")
            7 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("H")
            8 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("I")
            9 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("J")
            10 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("K")
            11 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("L")
            12 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("M")
            13 -> SomeFragment.newInstance("N")
            else -> SomeFragment.newInstance("0")
        }
    }
}
```

**SomeFragment:**

```
class SomeFragment : Fragment() {

    var TAG = "frg 0"

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        TAG = "frg ${arguments?.getString(CATEGORY)}"
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_some, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).apply {
            text = arguments?.let {
                it.getString(CATEGORY, "")
            } ?: "not found"
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart()")
        super.onStart()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume()")
        super.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause()")
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop()")
        super.onStop()
    }

    companion object {

        fun newInstance(
            categoryName: String
        ) = SomeFragment().apply {
            arguments = bundleOf(
                CATEGORY to categoryName
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**fragment_some.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CDDC39"
    tools:context=".fragments.SomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tablayout" />


    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**dependencies:**

```
// ViewPager2
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0-alpha01'
// CardView
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
// Tablayout + other stuff...
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

I tried to put some logs and see what's happening. I have 14 Fragments in the list and I select tab on position 9.

**Normal scenario** (not stopping debugger in `createFragment()` method):

```
2020-09-22 15:10:33.515 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 5
2020-09-22 15:10:33.534 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg F: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:10:33.552 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg D: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:10:33.573 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 6
2020-09-22 15:10:33.587 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg G: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:10:33.597 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 7
2020-09-22 15:10:33.609 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg H: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:10:33.633 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg C: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:10:33.636 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 8
2020-09-22 15:10:33.647 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg I: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:10:33.752 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg B: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:10:33.967 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 9
2020-09-22 15:10:33.972 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg A: onPause()
2020-09-22 15:10:33.973 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg A: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:10:34.018 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg F: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:10:34.023 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg I: onResume()
```

**Problematic scenario** (stopping debugger in `createFragment()` method for 1-2 seconds each time):

```
2020-09-22 15:14:26.419 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 5
2020-09-22 15:14:28.551 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg F: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:14:28.577 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg D: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:14:28.602 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 6
2020-09-22 15:14:29.591 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg G: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:14:29.615 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 7
2020-09-22 15:14:30.962 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg H: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:14:30.999 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg C: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:14:31.003 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg B: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:14:31.006 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 8
2020-09-22 15:14:31.922 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg I: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:14:31.956 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg A: onPause()
2020-09-22 15:14:31.957 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg A: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:14:31.965 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 9
2020-09-22 15:14:33.210 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg J: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:14:33.240 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg G: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:14:33.248 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 10
2020-09-22 15:14:34.247 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg K: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:14:34.276 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg F: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:14:34.280 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 11
2020-09-22 15:14:35.286 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg L: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:14:35.316 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg H: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:14:35.320 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 12
2020-09-22 15:14:36.407 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg M: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:14:36.435 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg I: onStop()
2020-09-22 15:14:36.439 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg: createFragment: 13
2020-09-22 15:14:37.632 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg N: onStart()
2020-09-22 15:14:37.656 26627-26627/com.example.viewpager2_example_2 D/frg J: onStop()
```

Anyone can explain what sort of sorcery is happening here inside `ViewPager2`?

Answer (score 2):

I made a fresh example, using:

```
Android Studio 4.0.1
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763, built on June 25, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.4.0-7642-generic
```

I basically did:

File, New Project, min API 26 (so I can run on my Nexus 5X), and picked the `Empty Activity` template.

I then one by one, added your code shared here, with very minor changes (for starters, your Layout contains a constrain to a `id/btn` that is not there, so I assume you only pasted the relevant bits, check [the layout xml in my repo](https://github.com/Gryzor/TabbedVp2/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml))

#### Results

Either when using no debugger attached (but obviously a debug build) or when placing a breakpoint in `createFragment()`, I still observe the expected behavior.

I tested on:

- Fast emulator (Pixel 3a with API 30)
- Real Nexus 5X with Android 8.1

I noticed that the fragments are correctly created when needed (only when I "swipe"); this is due to the `ExampleStateAdapter` being a subclass of `FragmentStateAdapter` which has a similar behavior by design to the original `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` which was good for large sets of pages where the creation is "lazy".

You can test this project very easily, I put it online in GitHub here:

https://github.com/Gryzor/TabbedVp2

#### Conclusion

Are you sure there is no other issue with your app causing an unnecessary delay when the fragments are managed? Something else in your layout that may be causing the measure/layout pass to take longer?

### Logs (filtering by `frg`)

#### Fresh App Start:

```
D/frg: createFragment: 0
D/frg A: onStart()
D/frg A: onResume()
```

All good here, the first fragment (0) is created and started.
Notice no Fragment B is "pre-created"; this may be a design choice by the fragment adapter, didn't look into its source code. This behavior is different starting with the next swipe...

#### Swipe to reveal Fragment B (and hide A):

```
1 D/frg: createFragment: 1
2 D/frg B: onStart()
3 D/frg: createFragment: 2
4 D/frg A: onPause()
5 D/frg B: onResume()
```

The only "strange" thing here, is the call to `createFragment: 2` in line 3. Let's see line by line:

1. Fragment 0 is the current, the next is "1" so the call is correct.
2. Fragment 1 ("b") is now being created and "started".
3. The State Adapter is preemptively creating Framgment "C" (number 2), but notice it's not yet Started or Resumed.
   *It did NOT do this for Fragment B when we were displaying Fragment A, this is by design I think, so if/when you show the first item, nothing is preemptively created; I wasn't aware of this, and I didn't inspect the source code, but that's how it behaves. From now on, every time a new fragment is created, the next is "pre-created" behind the scenes so it's ready to be started.*
4. As Fragment B is started, Fragment B is now paused as it goes off-screen.
5. Fragment B is finally resumed (After it was being started) as it's now visible.

#### Now Swipe back to "A" (for fun)

```
D/frg B: onPause()
D/frg A: onResume()
```

Not much to see, B is now paused and A is resumed, since it was created and started.

#### Let's swipe back to "B"

```
D/frg A: onPause()
D/frg B: onResume()
```

The inverse happens, nothing to see here.

#### Now let's swipe to C

```
1 D/frg C: onStart()
2 D/frg: createFragment: 3
3 D/frg B: onPause()
4 D/frg C: onResume()
```

1. C was pre-created, but never started, it is now Started.
2. Again, the adapter is pre-creating the next one ("D").
3. B is going away, so it's paused.
4. Finally C is resumed and visible.

#### Final Test, keep swiping to D...

```
1 D/frg D: onStart()
2 D/frg: createFragment: 4
3 D/frg A: onStop()
4 D/frg C: onPause()
5 D/frg D: onResume()
```

There was a reason why I wanted to reach "D" (or rather, be *far from A*) :)

Let's look at these logs

1. D was pre-created in the previous step in "1", so it's now started.
2. E is now being pre-created in case we swipe again.
3. A *is now stopped* and prone to be destroyed if needed. Since we've now gone beyond the default (3 total which is current + and - one if I correctly recall), the adapter is "stopping" unused Fragments to reclaim memory if needed. So A is semi-gone.
4. Now we pause C as usual, since it's going away in favor of D.
5. ...and Resume D, which was recently started.

At this point, you get the flow. If you keep going to "E", then Fragment "B" is going to be stopped:

```
D/frg E: onStart()
D/frg: createFragment: 5
D/frg B: onStop()
D/frg D: onPause()
D/frg E: onResume()
```

Business as usual.

#### UPDATE

I decided to test one more thing so I pushed [this commit](https://github.com/Gryzor/TabbedVp2/commit/e5442b1b8cb801a0d11e9268b171b34dcab1a7b6). It adds a button that will select the 10th fragment (which happens to be "K").

1. App Starts, `A` is Visible.

```
D/frg: createFragment: 0
D/frg A: onStart()
D/frg A: onResume()
```

2. Button is Pressed, `K` is now visible (after an animation)

```
01 D/frg: createFragment: 7
02 D/frg H: onStart()
03 D /frg: createFragment: 8
04 D/frg I: onStart()
05 D/frg: createFragment: 9
06 D/frg J: onStart()
07 D/frg: createFragment: 10
08 D/frg K: onStart()
09 D/frg: createFragment: 11
10 D/frg A: onPause()
11 D/frg A: onStop()
12 D/frg H: onStop()
13 D/frg K: onResume()
```

The position we're after is 10, it's really the 11th element because it's "zero based" (so A is zero, not 1).

The StateAdapter is trying to be smart (?) and is creating Fragment at position 7 (H), 8 (I), 9 (J), 10 (K) and 11 (L) as seen in lines 1, 3, 5, 7, and 9.

Here comes the Adapter's "intelligence" stupidity:

It goes one by one and starts them: H in line 2, I in line 4, J in line 6, and K in line 8.

Then it stops A (in Line 11) because it's outside of the scope of the state to maintain, and also stops H because for some reason it decided to start it preemptively, only to realize that it's no longer in "scope", so H gets stopped in line 12 too. Very inefficient here.

Finally K is "Resumed" since it's... well.. visible!

And here is **where the weird behavior I cannot explain starts**:
My questions to Google would be (possibly easy to answer if we take a look at the [state adapter's source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-collection-release/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter.java?source=post_page---------------------------%2F) but... who wants to do that now?).

- Why Is Fragment H started then stopped?
  My Theory is that the logic is triggered and H is exactly as far from "K" as "A" was from "D" (it has two other frags in between) so that's why it gets stopped afterwards, but why was it started?
- Why are fragments I, J (the ones in between H and K) Started too, BUT not stopped?

I assume this has to do with the same reason why when you swipe from C to D, A is stopped, but B and C aren't, they are paused. B would already been paused, and C gets paused when you go to D and A is stopped, but in this "jump" from A to K, these fragments are not PAUSED, which is a different state and possibly a bug. In a way, they are Started and not Resumed, so that's a "paused state", and that's why this works and is "kinda consistent".

I would have expected *at the very least* that I, and J be at least paused since that's how they would be if you swipe one by one, but the truth is they were never *resumed* so there's no reason to call Pause.

In the end, after this big "jump" from A to K, the fragments are in their *expected* state for being in Fragment K:

1. Nothing before (and including) "H" is created (or started/resumed). Correct.
2. Forwards wise (L and beyond) only "L" is pre-created (line 9 in the previous log where Fragment "11" is created but not started). Correct.
3. Fragments I, and J are "Started" and ready to go, but were never resumed so far (so they are paused). If you swipe "back" to J, it will be resumed (faster than having to create/start).

Well, there you have the behavior "documented" (not explained, since I didn't dig any further).

I hope this helps you clarify if anything, what the adapters are trying to do with your fragments and lifecycle. Now in older APIs and slow devices, this whole thing may take a few milliseconds (vs. very very few on newer devices).

#### Update II

If you disable the animation (either via the `TabLayoutMediator` as you found out, or the `viewPager.setCurrentItem(nn, false)` then this problem doesn't occur. This leads me to believe the "animation/transaction" system is being triggered as the "animation" to "go to the selected item" is being constructed and executed.

Meanwhile a [Google Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169172453) has been filed.

Comment: Hi Martin. First of all many thanks for detailed analysis! I had the same button to go directly to some tab, that's why @id/btn reference I forgot to remove. Next time asking here I'll just push my code to Github as well. Anyway, the issue is still happening for me even with your repo, see the screen recording: https://github.com/micer/TabbedVp2/blob/master/Screen%20Recording%202020-09-23%20at%2012.16.11%20PM.mov

Comment: I have taken a look and I can see it. I honestly think this is either a "bug" in the 'new' fragment manager or just a side-effect of the lag that having a debugger (or a slow device) (or... well.. both). Most of these things happens on the Main Thread (fragment transactions and lifecycle) so it appears the message queue is dropping stuff. Do you see any logs about the Choreographer dropping frames or similar? Any ANR?

Comment: What is really strange is that the `OnResume()` method is not being called at all for any of fragments. Just content of fragment "N" is visible. And all other fragments on the way seem to be "pre-created".

Comment: Well, the onResume will / should not be called unless the fragment is fully visible I think. Which in this case would be "K" (if the button does what it says). I see your logs and they appear to be doing a mess! Perhaps.. can you try adding `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-alpha08"` ? the latest says (source: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.0-alpha08) "new state manager"...

Comment: I just reproduced your issue and got the same, I landed on Fragment "N" instead of K. But K was selected in the Tabs. Just like your video. This is very weird. I'll be investigating further and maybe submitting an issue to the Google tracker if I have time to refine this (feel free to do so yourself and use my project or your fork, I don't mind).

Comment: (I often hang out in this [stack overflow chat room called Android Help](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210228/android-help) if you'd like to follow up :)

Comment: Ok nice, I'll keep investigating as well. Many thanks! Yeah I'll join the channel will be easier to communicate. ;-)

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same issue, thankss

Answer (score 0):

When you create TabLayoutMediator set smoothscroll false

`TabLayoutMediator(mTabLayout, mViewPager2, autorefresh = true, smoothScroll= false, TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy{ //your code })`

Comment: yes that helps, but then you loose smooth scrolling :-(

Answer (score 0):

I solved setting offscreenPageLimit some value, in my case I have 6 tabs and set the value to 3, it´s work really well. Now the performance is perfect!

Comment: Yes it's working and completely fine when having small number of tabs. But for more tabs with more complicated content I don't recommend this as they're not being recycled and it can cause memory issues on some low-end devices.